# Creating Java enums and classes with exact functionality but different names

Tags: java, enums

I have an enumeration with really long but descriptive name, I don't want to shorten the original name I just want to create a replication of the enumeration with different name. Such as;

```
public enum EnumWithLongButDescriptiveName {
    // code goes here
}
```

I want to have another enum with exact same functionality but with shorter name. Such as;

```
public enum EWLBDN {
    // preferably code goes here
}
```

So when I want to use my original enum in my code I don't want to reach it by typing the long name, but with the short name. But I don't want to delete the original enum.

Can I do that, if yes, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: If you will be using the short name in the code, why bother with the long name at all? I don't really understand the issue here.

Comment: Because I want my code to be understandable when read by someone else. So I want to be able to track `EnumWithLongButDescriptiveName` from `EWLBDN`.

Comment: Generally, you name the `enum` based on what they are supposed to represent. You can have the java docs above the `enum` for the description. Having a very long name for an `enum` is not a good practice.

Comment: Also, any decent IDE will be able to autocomplete the full name based on just a few letters, making it a moot point unless you're coding in Notepad or something.

Comment: If you can, shorten the name of the Enum and add a descriptive Javadoc instead. If you can not, and if you use Eclipse, try typing `EWLBDN`, hit auto-complete (Strg+Space), and see what happens.

Comment: I know there is auto-complete, I'm aware that some of you find this question nonsense, I just wonder if I'm able to do what I've asked.

Comment: @guneykayim - Nobody thinks that this question is non-sense. The fact that you've not been downvoted yet, should be enough to prove that. The comments here are just suggestions and general opinions of users being conveyed to you. There is nothing personal about this. :)

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I had a similar attitude in the past: short, barely descriptive names for private methods and stuff to speed up coding and making the code, seemingly, less cluttered. However, I eventually realized that doing so makes the code completely unreadable in the long run, especially if someone else is trying to understand/make changes to it. Saving half a second per call could cost hours and hours of people trying to read your code but being constantly interrupted by having to jump to method definitions and read the code to figure out what all the abbreviations mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about aliasing and extending isn't an option either, since Enums are final.
You can however create an `interface` that will be used to get certain keys from the Enum.

Enum:

```
public enum ReallyLongEnumNameWhichIsntActuallyAppropriate implements TinyEnum{
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE;

    @Override
    public ReallyLongEnumNameWhichIsntActuallyAppropriate getONE(){
        return ReallyLongEnumNameWhichIsntActuallyAppropriate.ONE;  
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface TinyEnum {

    public ReallyLongEnumNameWhichIsntActuallyAppropriate getONE();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution for you would be to statically import all values of the original enum in a class where you want to use them:

```
import static yourpackage.EnumWithLongAndDescriptiveName.*;
```

Personally I think, that you shouldn't try to create neither class nor enum with similar functionality, differing only by name, because it leads to code duplication and will make it harder to maintain and understand.

Especially when nowadays you have a lot of IDEs with great content assist which should make using even the longest names a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want some kind of aliasing, but this is not really supported. Aliasing a type is not possible at all in Java, which is one of its greatest weaknesses, IMHO.

The only thing you can do is to define constants with sufficiently short names, like:

```
 final public static EnumWithLongButDescriptiveName lne = EnumWithLongButDescriptiveName.LongNameEnum
```

Comment: OK, so I can't do aliasing, but I didn't understand how to define constant with short name. In your example you are defining a variable,  I'm asking for defining enum type? Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: @guneykayim You do not see the example? Here, you have something called `lne` that is the same as `EnumWithLongButDescriptiveName.LongNameEnum`

Comment: Yeah but isn't it just a variable? I'm asking for a type?

Comment: @guneykayim As I said, you can't alias a type, this is one of the greatest weaknesses of Java, IMHO.